# How to mock Angular HttpClient post call in karma unit test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I have the following code in my component's query() function, and I want to mock the results returned by http post, how can I do that?

```
query(){
    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson) .map((res) => res),
      this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson) .map((res) => res)
    )
    .subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mocking functionality available in angular TestBed and you can use that.

Make sure to import your HttpModule into test bed and then mock the http service.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
      ],
      providers: [
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Then call your service from fixture.

```
xxx = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(someService);
```

Then in yout test you can spyOn and say what you are expecting as return.

```
const error = spyOn(someService, 'someMethod').and.returnValue(
  Observable.throw({error: 'this is a error'})
);
```

Comment: how would the returnValue look if I return a value instead of an error?

Comment: you can directly say `Observable.of({something: 'somevalue'})` which will come to `.subscribe` block rather `.error` block